# Origen de la expresión "todo de perlas"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, historia, locuciones

Una amiga mia siempre me dice la expresión `todo de perlas` y a veces simplemente `de perlas`. Me gustaría saber de donde viene esta expresión y si es universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que sé, esta expresión sí es universal come un modismo muy común. La expresión se deriva del sustantivo "perla", que significa "pearl" en inglés.

> Persona 1: ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás?
>
> Persona 2: Todo de perlas.

Así, esta expresión significa que la situación está tan buena que todo que está ocurriendo es como perlas (porque las perlas son avocados con la riqueza y una situación cómoda). Similarmente, cuando se dice "me viene de perlas" significa "it was a godsend".

Answer (score 1):

La locución adverbial *de perlas* significa:

> **[de perlas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sex5L5a)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Perfectamente, [de molde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PYLm58e).

La expresión se usa pues para afirmar que algo es perfecto, o que se ajusta perfectamente a lo esperado.

Veo que la expresión ya la recoge el *Autoridades* (1737):

> De *perlas*. Modo adverb. con que se demuestra la propiedad con se dice ò hace alguna cosa, ò se acomoda à otra. [...] Siempre tuve respeto al matrimónio: pareceme *de perlas*, y mas si te has de casar.

El ejemplo que cita es de Lope de Vega, escrito en 1632, aunque he encontrado un caso anterior en el CORDE:

> *¡O, traydor, qué muger tiene! Y biéneseme de perlas aberlo conosçido, para poder yr allá y acariçiarla y conçertar mi negoçio.*
>
> Lorenzo Sepúlveda, "Comedia de Sepúlveda", c 1565 (España).

Y más atrás aún, en la *Segunda Celestina*, aparecen varios casos:

> *Esso me paresce de perlas.*
>
> *Por tanto, pues Dios tanto seso te dio, ordenemos aquí lo más sano, que en mi alma, que me ha parecido de perlas tu consejo, y que querría a mi señora Polandria más vella casada con este cavallero que con el emperador.*
>
> Feliciano de Silva, "Segunda Celestina", 1534 (España).

Viendo estos dos últimos ejemplos podría quedar claro el origen de la expresión. Si algo te parece "de perlas", es decir, que está hecho de perlas, es que es algo valioso, algo con lo que merece la pena quedarse, algo perfecto. Queda aún más claro con este ejemplo de la misma obra:

> *Hijo Centurio, algunos celos deves tú de tener pues que esso dizes, y en mi ánima, que me parece como de perlas, que nunca hay celos sino donde hay amor.*

Nótese el uso de "como de perlas" para dar más énfasis a la comparación que se está haciendo.

Por último, su uso parece bastante extendido, pues además de en España encuentro en el CREA casos de la expresión en textos de Argentina, Chile, México y Costa Rica.

---

Curiosidad: la palabra *perla* aparece como de "etimología discutida". Corominas dice:

> **PERLA**, h. 1440. Probablemente del latín vulgar *PERNULA, propiamente diminutivo del latín PERNA 'especie de ostra'. La forma castellana se tomó de otro romance (catalán, francés o italiano, en todos los cuales ya se halla en el siglo XIII).